# FreeBSD Ethernet Manipulation

Tags: c, perl, networking, freebsd, ethernet

I need a method to perform the following task, suppose if I have a computer with k (k is large) number of Ethernet interfaces. I want to have a method to identify which identifier (em0) is assigned to which physical interface.

The only "easy" method that I came up is to blink the LED light on the physical interface.

For example

```
etherblink em0
```

Would flash the link or the activity LED on the physical Ethernet interface that is assigned to em0.

I know on linux there is the ethertool, but that doesn't work with FreeBSD. As well as there is the LED driver on FreeBSD, but that only support limited number of Ethernet modules.

Any ideas? I thought about binding a socket to the interface and write to the socket, but that didn't work.

C or Perl

Comment: Yes, you can, and I'm embarrassed I can't remember how. Did you ask on the FreeBSD forum? http://forums.freebsd.org/

Comment: Yes, I did, time to wait to see if I can get a working answer/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I did not find a general solution to this problem, however, from my research (by reading the change log of FreeBSD 8.2, and from the forums) It seems that:

```
"some cards blink the LEDs on access, so pings could make a repeated pattern. 
The LEDs might even go off if the card is downed with ifconfig(8)."
```

Particularly em and igb interfaces, as stated by:

```
"The em(4) and igb(4) drivers now support the led(4) interface via /dev/led/emN and 
/dev/led/igbN for identification LED control. The following command line makes the 
LED blink on em0:[r211241]" (FreeBSD 8.2 Release changelog)
```

However I do not have the hardware to test this. What I did end up doing was rewritten the Ethernet driver for the interface that I am using to support the LED hardware feature.

Answer (score 2):

Tough I have not done this, but, according to FreeBSD handbook, it's possible to bind specific driver node to specific hardware IRQ using kernel configuration hints. See device.hints(5) and [FreeBSD network setup](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/config-network-setup.html) to see how to locate each Ethernet device IRQ.

Comment: I will certainly look into this when I have more free time.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the interface in question is `fxp0`... run this as root

```
use strict; 
my $intf = "fxp0";
while (1) { 
    foreach my $state (qw/up down/) {
        system("ifconfig $intf $state\n");
        sleep 3;
    }
}
```

I assume you won't care about transfering data through the interface while it's blinking...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this did not help with what I was doing, the LED light stayed off.

Comment: This is the first I can recall hearing of an ethernet interface that did not link up when you turned it on... did you try a longer frequency (say 10 seconds?)

Comment: I didn't have a cable plugged in, also, it was a SBC from Sokeris engineering.

Comment: @bill, you you plug cables into all your ethernet ports on the server, this would work